# How to use ngl-picklist with Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular4-forms, ng-lightning

I am trying to build a nested reactive form in angular 4. The form will be based on the following model:

`...
    this.trunkForm = this._fb.group({
      deviceName: [''],
      ipAddresses: this._fb.array([])
    });
    ...`

One can associate as many pre-existing `ipAddresses` to a deviceName.
If you need more info like a plunker, let me know. I will create one.

I wanted to use the  component from ng-lightning-v2.0.1, to display a list of pre-defined ipAddresses. But when I use ngl-picklist and assign it a **formControlName**, I get a "No value accessor for form control" error.

What is the correct way to use ngl-picklist in an Angular 4 reactive form (nested)?